# What are the difference between adding a property to instance or adding to prototypeproperty?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following class:

```
      class PersonCl {
      constructor(fullName, age) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age= age;
      }
    
      // Instance methods
      // Methods will be added to .prototype property
      calcAge() {
        console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
      }
    
      greet() {
        console.log(`Hey ${this.fullName}`);
      }
}
```

now i have lets say two object that were created from the constructor:

```
const Joe = new PersonCl('Joe',23);
const Larisa = new PersonCl('Larisa',41);
```

i'm asking what is the difference between:

1.adding the property *species* into constructor and set it  exactly where we set the fullName and age.

2. or adding the following line outside the class declaration:

   PersonCl.prototype.species = "Male";

Comment: Is Larisa really male? If no, it makes no sense for her to share that property with Joe.

Comment: @What do you mean share?

Comment: Do you understand how prototype inheritance works? Where are you learning about it?

Comment: From a video. I hope i understand. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "species" property placed on the prototype object will be visible on all instances in *most* (but not *all* situations). As soon as your code makes a change to "species":

```
someInstance.species = "tiger";
```

then that instance will have a *local* property "species", and the value of "species" on other instances will not change.

Clearly, when the property is directly added to instances in the constructor, all instances will be similarly initialized (given your sample code) but thereafter changes can still be made on an instance-by-instance basis. The key point is that updating a property value on an object always makes a local, "own" property of that object and does not affect the prototype.

Some methods intended to help work with object properties as a collection, like `Object.keys()`, *only* involve "own" properties, which means properties directly associated with an object and not inherited properties.

Comment: can you please say to which solution (one or two) you refer to?

Comment: @Eitanos30 I will clarify the answer.

Comment: does `PersonCl.prototype.species = "Male";` is making `species` like a static property?  objects can only have a local `species` but the value that is inherited will always be "Male"?

Comment: @Eitanos30 it's not really like a "static" property. Any property on the prototype will be visible (with caveats, as described in the answer) on instances. Usually, the prototype object is used for methods that should be shared for all members of the class. However, simple values like strings or numbers also work.

Comment: @Eitanos30 usually in JavaScript "static" is used to describe properties on the constructor function itself, not on properties of the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prototype is a real object
2. A lot of objects could have the same prototype
3. Prototype could have prototype too
4. When you read object property JS will look for own property first, and if it does not exists, it will look for this property in prototype and in prototype of prototype, etc.